# Android webView scroll issue

Tags: android, android-webview

I try to make webView height wrap_content and use for scrolling an external scrollview. But in my case scrolls only webView and other views which placed below, not shown. I need to show checkbox and buttons just below the webView. Here is my layout. Probably there is some way to disable scrolling inside of webView? Does anyone trying to do something like this?

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/signup_title_complete_registration"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/signup_subtitle_complete_registration"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/disclosureWv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chekBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="@={viewModel.agree}"
            android:drawableEnd="?android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/signup_title_agreement_checkbox"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/previousBtn"
                style="@style/Button.White.BlueStroke"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onPreviousClicked()}"
                android:text="@string/general_button_previous_step"
                android:textColor="?android:textColorTertiaryInverse"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
                style="@style/Button.Positive"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:enabled="@{viewModel.enabled}"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onNextClicked()}"
                android:text="@string/general_button_next"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

how can i reach that behavior?

Comment: Try adding `android:focusable="false"` to the WebView.

Comment: Didn't help. Still scrolling

Comment: @ DanMan make `android:layout_height="match_parent"` as `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in webview

Comment: I've already tried. In this case content trimmed from bottom. There is a text in the beginning then begins a white screen till the bottom

Comment: have you try this on WeightSum of Linearlayout..?

Comment: Yes i have. I set weight = 1 to webView. WebView take a half of screen pressed by other views in the layout. WebView content scrolls but whole layout doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView content was trimmed only on emulator. When i built the app on a real device everything became fine